# Table with no wrap, one column with overflow and as big as possible

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed-width table of 400px with 3 columns.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="wide">This is really really long and as much as possible should show but should eventually be cut off.</td><td class="narrow">Small1</td><td class="narrow">Small2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS.

```
table
{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 400px;
}
td
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td.wide
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
td.narrow
{
}
```

[Here is the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jer4C/3/)

Currently, each of the 3 columns takes up 1/3 of the space.  What I want is for the 2nd and 3rd columns to be as small as possible (without anything hidden or text-wrapped) and have the 1st column take up the remainder of the space (with any text that doesn't fit being hidden).

Depending on the data displayed, the 2nd and 3rd columns may need to be wider or narrower to fit their content, so I don't want to define a fixed size for any column.

Is this possible?

Comment: What behaviour do you want to see if content of first column is wider than remaining size ?

Comment: @OlivierH: If the text in column 1 doesn't fit, I'd like it to be hidden, preferably with ellipsis.  I edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the only solution i found. It's pretty ugly but it does the trick :

http://jsfiddle.net/XA9kY/

The thing is to wrap the string to be overflowing into a .... `table`

---

Notice the `table` into the `td.wide`

```
<div style="width:400px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="wide">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>This is really really long and as much as possible should show but should eventually be cut off.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="narrow">Small1</td>
                <td class="narrow">Small2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

And here is the magic

```
td.wide table
{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td.wide table td
{
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Just wrapping the string into a `table` with `table-layout: fixed;` property does the trick.

Comment: This won't work.  Then the table will extend well beyond the desired 400px and the text will not be cut off as desired.

Comment: Yes i forgot this part : I edit my answer as soon as the OP answer my question (comment on the first post)

Comment: The problem with 'table-layout: auto;' is that the table will expand with the content to greater than the set-width of the surrounding div.  [Here is the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jer4C/5/)

Comment: This is normal : you told neither of your div to wrap at any moment. Please answer my question in a comment to your post, i'll edit my answer with a working solution.

Comment: Instead of adding the inner table in the html of the page, I wound up adding this to the bottom of the page (uses JQuery):
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('td.Wide').each(function () {
        $(this).html('<table><tbody><tr><td>' + $(this).html() + '</td></tr></tbody></table>');
    });
    </script>

Answer (score 2):

Here's my try at this: [(**Example**)](http://jsfiddle.net/alexnho/YFKws/)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="wide">This is really really long and as much as possible should show but should eventually be cut off.</td>
            <td class="rest">Small1</td>
            <td class="rest">Small2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width: 400px;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
td.rest {
    width:1px;
}
```

The only thing is that it doesn't like:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

If that isn't an issue then this should work.

**EDIT**
A possible solution to hide the text in the wider cell by just setting the height.
Added also the line-height for all the cells so you can change both based on the settings you're after.
Here the [(Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/alexnho/4Sbw6/)

```
table {
    width: 400px;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    line-height:26px;
}
td.rest {
    width:1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td.wide {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:26px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I edited my original question to clarify that I'd like extra text in the first column to be hidden.  Your solution in your EDIT is an interesting hack.